# get all choice values from the field using powershell CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, csom, choice-field

How can we retrieve all the choice values in the choice field
using powershell CSOM

i hardly could not find any resources for this functionality

any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can check [this](https://www.splessons.com/get-choice-field-values-using-client-side-object-model-in-sharepoint-2013/) link here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerShell command below:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$WebURL="http://intranet.crescent.com/"
$ListName ="Projects"
$MultiChoiceFieldName="Category"

$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.lists.TryGetList($ListName)
#Get the 1st item stored in the list
$Item = $List.items[0]

#Get the multiple choice field 
$MultiChoiceValues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue($Item[$MultiChoiceFieldName])

#Print Each Value
For($I=0; $I -lt $MultiChoiceValues.count; $I++)
{            
 write-host $MultiChoiceValues[$I]
}
```

Reference: [Get-Set Choice Field Value in SharePoint using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/04/powershell-to-get-set-choice-field-value-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: we need powershell Csom script to run it on sharepoint online